# Jenkins - how to run pipeline only if no other job is running on agent/master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to implement a maintenance job for cleaning up caches (e.g. Maven, NPM).
In order not to disturb running jobs by deleting the caches the maintenance job should only run, if no other job is running on that node.

Any ideas are welcome that not include refactoring already implemented pipelines and by locking resources.

I also tried [throttle concurrents plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/throttle-concurrents/) but without success.

###### Pipeline

```
def allNodes = nodesByLabel label: 'master'
def otherNodes = nodesByLabel label: '!master'
allNodes.addAll(otherNodes)

Map tasks = [:]

for (int i = 0; i < allNodes.size(); i++) {
    def label = allNodes[i]
    if ( label.isEmpty() ) {
        label = "master"
    }

    def stageName = "Clean ${type} cache on node: ${label}"
    tasks[label] = {
        node(label) {
            stage(stageName) {
                sh("rm -rf ${env.NPM_CACHE_DIR}")
            }
        }
    }
}

throttle(['jenkinsAdministrationCleanCache']) {
    parallel(tasks)
}
```

###### Throttle config

```
unclassified:
  throttleJobProperty:
    categories:
    - categoryName: "jenkinsAdministrationCleanCache"
      maxConcurrentTotal: 1
      maxConcurrentPerNode: 1
```